# What does a Data Mapper typically look like?

Tags: php, orm, datamapper

I have a table called `Cat`, and an PHP class called `Cat`. Now I want to make a `CatDataMapper` class, so that `Cat extends CatDataMapper`.

I want that Data Mapper class to provide basic functionality for doing ORM, and for creating, editing and deleting Cat.

For that purpose, maybe someone who knows this pattern very well could give me some helpful advice? I feel it would be a little bit too simple to just provide some functions like update(), delete(), save().

I realize a Data Mapper has this problem: First you create the instance of Cat, then initialize all the variables like name, furColor, eyeColor, purrSound, meowSound, attendants, etc.. and after everything is set up, you call the save() function which is inherited from CatDataMapper. This was simple ;)
But now, the real problem: You query the database for cats and get back a plain boring result set with lots of cats data.

PDO features some ORM capability to create Cat instances. Lets say I use that, or lets even say I have a mapDataset() function that takes an associative array. However, as soon as I got my Cat object from a data set, I have redundant data. At the same time, twenty users could pick up the same cat data from the database and edit the cat object, i.e. rename the cat, and save() it, while another user still things about setting another furColor. When all of them save their edits, everything is messed up.

Err... ok, to keep this question really short: What's good practice here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [DataMapper in PoEA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

> The Data Mapper is a layer of software
>   that separates the in-memory objects
>   from the database. Its responsibility
>   is to transfer data between the two
>   and also to isolate them from each
>   other. With Data Mapper the in-memory
>   objects needn't know even that there's
>   a database present; they need no SQL
>   interface code, and certainly no
>   knowledge of the database schema. (The
>   database schema is always ignorant of
>   the objects that use it.) Since it's a
>   form of Mapper (473), Data Mapper
>   itself is even unknown to the domain
>   layer.

Thus, a Cat should not extend CatDataMapper because that would create an is-a relationship and tie the Cat to the Persistence layer. If you want to be able to handle persistence from your Cats in this way, look into [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) or any of the other Data Source Architectural Patterns.

You usually use a DataMapper when using a Domain Model. A simple DataMapper would just map a database table to an equivalent in-memory class on a field-to-field basis. However, when the need for a DataMapper arises, you usually won't have such simple relationships. Tables will not map 1:1 to your objects. Instead multiple tables could form into one Object Aggregate and viceversa. Consequently, implementing *just* CRUD methods, can easily become quite a challenge.

Apart from that, it is one of the more complicated patterns (covers 15 pages in PoEA), often used in combination with the [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) among others. Look into the related questions column on the right side of this page for similar questions.

As for your question about multiple users editing the same Cat, that's a common problem called [Concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29). One solution to that would be [locking the row](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28database%29), while someone edits it. But like everything, this can [lead to other issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Comment: I have a question regarding Data mapper vs Table Data gateway (TDG). TDG pattern tables maps 1:1 with a table, but often in some TDG class methods, we need to join the main table with other tables (to join with some parent tables to select additional info). Does such a thing violates Table Data gateway pattern? IMHO as soon as you add other DB tables (even joins) in SQL statements in TDG class methods, or split your model (domain model or table data) classes into two - the class becomes a Data mapper class. IMHO Data Mapper is just a normal evolution of your TDG classes.

Comment: Also, if your implemented data source class is capable to connect to various sources (DB or some webservice) then IMHO you have implemented Data mapper class.

Comment: Fowler states in POEAA that a TDG may contain the code to access many tables/views so I guess you may do JOINs in it as well. But of course that means the returned results will no longer match 1:1 to the tables and you will need specialized Update and Insert queries for those rows in addition to generic ones. I can see how that makes you conclude that it looks like Data Mapper but the purpose of Data Mapper is really much more complex than just that. It's not just JOIN => DataMapper . Have a look at http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns-data

Comment: Yes, I agree DataMapper is for more complex tasks. What about different datasources? If my implemented TDG class is capable to connect to various sources (DB or some web service, depending on passed parameter to constructor) then IMHO my class is no longer TDG class, and is more Data Mapper class? I assume sometimes it might be hard to be theoretically strict: is a datasource class implementing Table Gateway or Data Mapper pattern.

Comment: I'd argue in that case its more like a [Remote Facade](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html). But why not just buy the book? It's a classic anyway.

Comment: Definitely :) Thanks. Also, it's always a good practice to discuss with someone who has a knowledge in that.

Comment: One more question: from a practical data mapper use, I see that one of the main data mapper pattern implementation advantages is to have some 'Context_manager' or 'Entity_manager' that handles all CRUD operations in schema. For example, I have a lot of domain model classes that might not or be related 1:1 with a db tables. I can instantiate domain model classes, modify and mark those entity objects for saving (when manipulating them). Then, just one call to entity_manager.save() handles and saves all changes in db. It's very performance-wise solution because all sql is done in one transaction.

Comment: These assumptions are made from Doctrine 2: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html

Answer (score 2):

If you rely on ORM's like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/), the basic principle is to create a static class that would get the actual data from the database, (for instance Propel would create CatPeer), and the results retrieved by the Peer class would then be "hydrated" into Cat objects.

The hydration process is the process of converting a "plain boring" MySQL result set into nice objects having getters and setters.

So for a retrieve you'd use something like `CatPeer::doSelect()`. Then for a new object you'd first instantiate it (or retrieve and instance from the DB): 
`$cat = new Cat();`

The insertion would be as simple as doing: `$cat->save();` That'd be equivalent to an insert (or an update if the object already exists in the db... The ORM should know how to do the difference between new and existing objects by using, for instance, the presence ort absence of a primary key).

Answer (score 1):

> PDO features some ORM capability to
>   create Cat instances. Lets say I use
>   that, or lets even say I have a
>   mapDataset() function that takes an
>   associative array. However, as soon as
>   I got my Cat object from a data set, I
>   have redundant data. At the same time,
>   twenty users could pick up the same
>   cat data from the database and edit
>   the cat object, i.e. rename the cat,
>   and save() it, while another user
>   still things about setting another
>   furColor. When all of them save their
>   edits, everything is messed up.

In order to keep track of the state of data typically and IdentityMap and/or a UnitOfWork would be used keep track of all teh different operations on mapped entities... and the end of the request cycle al the operations would then be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a Data Mapper is very hard in PHP < 5.3, since you cannot read/write protected/private fields. You have a few choices when loading and saving the objects:

1. Use some kind of workaround, like serializing the object, modifying it's string representation, and bringing it back with unserialize
2. Make all the fields public
3. Keep them private/protected, and write mutators/accessors for each of them

The first method has the possibility of breaking with a new release, and is very crude hack, the second one is considered a (very) bad practice.

The third option is also considered bad practice, since you should not provide getters/setters for all of your fields, only the ones that need it. Your model gets "damaged" from a pure DDD (domain driven design) perspective, since it contains methods that are only needed because of the persistence mechanism. 
It also means that now you have to describe another mapping for the fields -> setter methods, next to the fields -> table columns.

PHP 5.3 introduces the ability to access/change all types of fields, by using reflection:

http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php

With this, you can achieve a true data mapper, because the need to provide mutators for all of the fields has ceased.

Answer (score 0):

keep the answer short:
You have an instance of Cat. (Maybe it extends CatDbMapper, or Cat3rdpartycatstoreMapper)
You call:

```
$cats = $cat_model->getBlueEyedCats();
//then you get an array of Cat objects, in the $cats array
```

Don't know what do you use, you might take a look at some php framework to the better understanding.

Comment: I think you described ActiveRecord, not DataMapper.